# I miss a hangover

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

I've been watching *Person of Interest*, [Episode 12](https://subslikescript.com/series/Person_of_Interest-1839578/season-1/episode-12-Legacy). Part of a conversation in that goes like this:

[The conversation is between two guys who don't like each other at all but because of their jobs they have to put up with eachother]

> A: Miss me?

> B: Yeah, like I miss a hangover.

What does the "I miss a hangover mean" here, as I have searched and found nothing...

Comment: What movie.  There has been more than one movie made in America in the last few year (or so I've heard)

Comment: @JamesK Thanks for the answer, I just didn't want to bring the name of the movie since I found that having a lot of ironic and sometimes evil purposes behind its apparent story, either way the movie is Person of Interest, Episode 12.

Comment: Thank you I'll add that to the question. You must give the source of the phrase. [Here's Why](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ironic simile.  A hangover is the feeling you get after drinking heavily.  You have a headache, dry mouth and feel tired.

You "miss" somebody, when you want them while they are away.

Nobody likes a hangover.  Nobody "misses" a hangover. So 'A' asks "Did you want me while I was away?"  And 'B' replies "I wanted you as much as I want to have a hangover - that is I didn't want you at all!"

Comment: Compare "I need this problem like I need a hole in the head".